# How can I make code indentation behave correctly in vbhtml razor files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, indentation

This is driving me round the bend. I'm a long time `VB.NET` forms developer, quite new to `ASP.NET` and completely new to `MVC`. I'm creating `vbhtml` pages that use the `VB.NET Razor` syntax, and I seem to be constantly fighting against the `UI` which is trying to indent my code incorrectly. Take the following example, based on the template page for a new `Razor` view:

```
@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @If True Then
            @<ul>
                @For x = 1 To 2

                Next
            </ul>
                End If '<-- Randomly indented too far
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, as soon as I hit return after `Next`, `End If` two lines below randomly jumps two tabs forward from where it should be. In other examples I've hit a circle where pushing one line to the correct place throws another line out of position and vice versa.

I'm so annoyed at this point I'd be happy to disable auto-indentation completely and just manage it myself, but I can't even find out how to do that! Following advice on another thread I disabled indentation for `HTML` pages but all that stops is indentation of `HTML` tags - the code blocks still slide around all over the place.

I thought an extension might be causing the problem but I disabled them all and restarted and the problem remains. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? I find it hard to believe `Microsoft` would release something so poor so it seems more likely I'm just not using it right.

Comment: I think you can use "Format the whole document" option which is part of "HTML source editing" tool in visual studio. Alternately you can use command (Ctrl+E, D) on regular basis to format the document.

Comment: @Pramodtech: In my environemt, Ctrl+E, D brings up the "Add existing file" dialog, but I tried Ctrl+K, D which does seem to format the whole document. Trouble is, it garbles the document even worse than it was before. It seems like MS have a serious bug in the auto-indentation of vbhtml which I find really surprising given how polished VS is generally.

Comment: @wwarby It's not just VB, it affect C# too, which makes it all the more stupifying that it's not yet been addressed.

Comment: There is a bug report in Microsoft Connect here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/621084

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Visual Studio code formatting work properly for Razor markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902204/why-doesnt-visual-studio-code-formatting-work-properly-for-razor-markup)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution (of a fashion) on another question (I really did search hard before posting this question and couldn't find anything): [Why doesn't Visual Studio code formatting work properly for Razor markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902204/why-doesnt-visual-studio-code-formatting-work-properly-for-razor-markup)

Essentially the solution seems to be to ensure that your code uses spaces instead of tabs for the whitespace. Whilst increasing the overall size of the page because of increased whitespace, it does lessen the problem (whilst not eliminating it completely). On the linked thread, someone who appears to be connected with Microsoft has acknowledged it is indeed a bug related to the overlapping formatters for HTML and VB.NET which they hope to improve in a new release. I've dropped to 2 spaces per indent to lessen the bandwidth impact.

Thanks to the guys who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative here(rather than using spaces for tabs), is to change the block indenting for HTML and C#/VB to "Block" instead of "Smart". This isn't a full solution, but IMO is a far less painful work-around than using spaces!