# Razor formatting of <text> contents

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, indentation

I've noticed that the Razor `<text>` tag refuses to follow any formatting conventions. For example, when formatting a `cshtml` document, I end up with code like the following:

```
@MyHelper.MyMethod(@<div>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>)

@MyHelper.MyMethod(@<text>
<p>Hello world</p>
</text>)
```

<sub>Note that this isn't specific to Razor template functions either, `<text>` blocks anywhere will do the same thing.</sub>

The client HTML tags (*and their contents*) such as `<div>` follow the formatting style I've specified, however regardless of where I add (*or remove*) the `<text>` element in the <kbd>Tag Specific Options...</kbd>, there is no effect. The desired result would be that the `<text>` element contents be formatted like the `<div>` element contents, in the previous example.

Are there any tricks, or work-arounds to enforcing the same formatting style on `<text>` elements as that of other block-level client HTML elements (*`<div>`, `<section>`, etc.*)

I've seen other such formatting issues with the Razor language, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269660/how-can-i-make-code-indentation-behave-correctly-in-vbhtml-razor-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902204/why-doesnt-visual-studio-code-formatting-work-properly-for-razor-markup), so this isn't without precedent and it seems likely there may be no solution. Either way, maybe someone has come across a fix.

<sub>It's a Razor 2.X website, building in VS 2010</sub>

---

**Addendum**
<sup>(*I've grown weary of this.*)</sup>

Perhaps this issue has been solved in 2012; don't know, haven't updated. However, `<text>` blocks, `@`-prefixed blocks, and more do not format well.

Another example, this time the `@`-prefixed blocks (*constructs and such*)

```
@foreach (var foo in bar) {
    <div>@(foo.A)</div>
    <div>@(foo.B)</div>
    @foreach (var qux in foo.C) {
        <div>@(qux.D)</div>
        <div>@(qux.E)</div>
    }
}
```

Looks more or less fine, right? Yea, unfortunately it's actually syntactically invalid. The `@`-prefix on the inner `foreach` is not permitted, as it occurs within the uninterrupted scope of an outer block (*the outer `foreach`*).

The solution? Omit the `@` from the inner `foreach`. What happens when I format?

```
@foreach (var foo in bar) {
    <div>@(foo.A)</div>
    <div>@(foo.B)</div>
    foreach (var qux in foo.C) {
    <div>@(qux.D)</div>
    <div>@(qux.E)</div>
    }
}
```

Awesome, lost the inner indentation. Poo.

Ok, how about those `<text>` blocks, they must be useful for something, right? Sure, wrap the contents of the outer `foreach` block in a `<text>` block. Now, as far as Razor is concerned, `@`-prefixing the inner `foreach` is syntactically valid.

```
@foreach (var foo in bar) {
    <text>
    <div>@(foo.A)</div>
    <div>@(foo.B)</div>
    @foreach (var qux in foo.C) {
        <div>@(qux.D)</div>
        <div>@(qux.E)</div>
    }
    </text>
}
```

Ok, *fine*; however, while this works it does exemplify my original question's issue. *Now the `<text>` block contents aren't adhering to indentation*. Why can't we just have:

```
@foreach (var foo in bar) {
    <text>
        <div>@(foo.A)</div>
        <div>@(foo.B)</div>
        @foreach (var qux in foo.C) {
            <div>@(qux.D)</div>
            <div>@(qux.E)</div>
        }
    </text>
}
```

Or better yet, screw the `<text>` block and permit `@`-prefixed constructs within the scope of others:

```
@foreach (var foo in bar) {
    <div>@(foo.A)</div>
    <div>@(foo.B)</div>
    @foreach (var qux in foo.C) {
        <div>@(qux.D)</div>
        <div>@(qux.E)</div>
    }
}
```

**tl;dr**

Call me anal, call me insane. Doesn't matter; so far as I can tell, this product is not working correctly, regardless of my formatting settings.

**Does anyone know how to force VS 2010 Razor formatting to behave as described? (*or, is this just some pipe-dream for my OCD?*)**

Comment: This is just plain sad. The solution to this, and nearly every Razor formatting issue is: **Don't format your document**. Frankly, that's bullshit. Issues like this, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829012/the-system-web-razor-api-documentation) lead me to assume there's an awful lot of deadlines which are just "being met".

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for it would be:

1. Right click on the `cshtml` file
2. Open with...
3. Choose `XML (Text) Editor`
4. Press **CTRL + E, D**

Comment: +1 It's a "solution" ;) - I've neglected to mention I've got CodeMaid with "Format on Save", so I needn't format documents manually. I suppose that's part of the problem in a way, that I've forgone control of when I format the documents. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, however I don't know if this is a feasible, long-term solution.