# Asp.net core razor view is not formatted

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

The razor view formatting is so bad
even when I tried ctrl k + ctrl d

the page is so missed up

any help, please!

[image]

```
     @if (item.Details.Length > 10)
                        {
    @item.Details.ToString().Substring(0, 10) }
else
{
@item.Details}
```

Comment: To get a useful answer you'll need to provide some code and be specific about what you're asking for.

Comment: Can you give your picture again? We cannot see the picture you provided.

Comment: I added the picture @YihuiSun

Comment: What IDE/editor are you using?

Comment: Visual studio 2019 @michaela112358

Comment: You could try Options > Environment >Preview Features> Enable experimental Razor editor to see if that improves it any. I'd say even with that it still isn't great when it comes to stuff like @if and brackets.

Comment: still got the same isuue @michaela112358

Comment: Selecting Options > Text Editor > Razor > Tabs and change "Keep tabs" to "Insert spaces" seemed to finally fix it for me.

Comment: also a few more suggestions on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902204/why-doesnt-visual-studio-code-formatting-work-properly-for-razor-markup?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Visual Studio code formatting work properly for Razor markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902204/why-doesnt-visual-studio-code-formatting-work-properly-for-razor-markup)

Answer (score 2):

You can **enable the new Razor editor** first, and then **restart VS**.

- [**New experimental Razor editor for Visual Studio**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/new-experimental-razor-editor-for-visual-studio/)

Then you can choose **Edit->Advanced->Format Document**.

[image]

### ✎[Edit]

You can try the following methods:

1. **Check** whether **three-party plug-ins** are installed.

   - If there are three-party plug-ins installed, **temporarily disable** them, and then test it.
2. You can try **reset VS settings**.

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings
   - Change the fourth step to select the General option.
3. **Repair** VS (repair in **VS Installer**)
4. **Create** a new project and check if the same problem occurs.
5. **Clean up** the program **/project/VS** cache, then **restart VS** and try again.

   - The project **is cached** in the **solution/project** folder,you need to **delete the bin, obj and .vs files**.
   - VS is cached in this path: **C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_XXXXXXXXX**, **delete** all **ComponentModelCache** folder.
6. **Give feedback to** the **VS product** group from **VS-> Help-> Send Feedback-> Report a Problem...**

Comment: This is very strange. The version of VS I am currently using is 16.9.2 (but not the latest version). You can see that I can format the code correctly. I suggest you can try again after updating the latest version of VS. The problem you encounter may be caused by the version of VS you are using.

Comment: I have the latest version of VS and the problem still there.

Comment: I updated the reply, you can check it out.